# Just found a vintage Sears & Roebuck 'Ted Williams' Free Spirit 3 wheeler. Can I modernize it?

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel, framebuilding

It's been in my girlfriends back yard for years and I'm under the impression that it's a pretty uncommon bike because I can't find any information on it. Her stepfather spray painted a camo pattern on it, changed out the original handle bars and seat for some Mongoose crap, crashed it, then left it to rot. I just decided to make it a project and was wondering if anyone knew the specs on it and if I could use modern 24" BMX parts on it.

[image: Sears & Roebuck 'Ted Williams' Free Spirit 3 wheeler]

The only salvageable parts are the frame, rear axle, and basket frame (basket is MIA), it basically needs a complete rebuild and I thought it would be funny to turn it into a pseudo BMX bike. My biggest concern is finding modern wheels for the rear axel.

I'm sure I'll have plenty more questions as I get into this bike a bit more.

Comment: Whats the rear frame spacing? If its not too much from a modern 24 inch wheel, you could just spread the frame (since it is likely steel, since you said vintage [ you can't spread other materials ] ). Also, can you post some pictures?

Comment: @Batman frame spacing is about 24" on those things.

Comment: @NickBastardly I pasted your question title into DuckDuckGo and got a restoration discussion and some pictures. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Sears+%26+Roebuck+%27Ted+Williams%27+Free+Spirit+3+wheeler.

Comment: Awesome, that's the bike in the photo. I would upload my own but it's already in pieces and I didn't think to take pictures untill after I was already invested in the disassembly. It's a shame that the value was already lost when the frame was painted...not to mention the rust. Anyway, I started looking around for parts and I think I may just have to buy aftermarket 36H trike hubs from a low rider site and lace them to new rims. My next question, does this have a euro bottom bracket and are all euro BB's the same?

Comment: You can cut off the fender guards and put pretty much any size wheel on there. I go to Goodwill to pick up junk bikes (including kids bikes) for their parts.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, anything is possible, especially if you have access to a oxy-gas welding or brazing torch (or arc/MIG/TIG welder), a grinder with a cut-off wheel and a willingness to cause mayhem.

As a BMX, it'll be heavy and ungainly, especially around corners. When you pedal, it'll pull to one side as it doesn't have a differential, but it'll be tons of fun and something different.

Why not put a really big wheel on front and turn it into a rocking trike?

Comment: It doesn't really make much of a difference to me. I just wanted to troll the local BMX clique with a trike that has all the same "bells and whistles" as their 20" BMX.